# delete employees whose manager location is usa

Tags: sql

How to delete the emp whose manager is in New York?

Employee table

```
empid       name           salary          location
101          john          10000           newyork
102          pavan         25000           newyork
103          laxman        10000           ahmedabad
104          ram           15000           usa
105          arjun         30000           washington
106          gopal         12000           washington
```

Table department columns

```
empid       dept    managerid
101         a        102
102         a
103         a         102
104         b         105
105         b         
106         b         105
```

Comment: [What have you tried? Why didn't it work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13640393/employee-and-manager-who-is-in-the-same-location)

Comment: [Exact dupplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13640393/1297603) please quit repeating the answer, edit the original one to get some answers.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi, in a couple of hours, two questions, with almost exactly same data to test, with little variations between titles and question. IMO this is a duplicate, therefore the OP needs to edit original question and give more information, following the basic advices given on comments.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi absolutely no, don't get me wrong, I have done that before too, using same data to ask. But to ask totally different questions and trying to follow the advices given. Or either asking two questions but one is a continuation of the other and not similar issues.

Comment: Sorry yar iam new to this sql just learning in internet and practticing different scenerios.. am just paracticing different reqrmnts on the same data.. thats it.. :(

Comment: @Pinky - sorry StackOverflow is not a 20-questions site for self-learning tutorials. It's for people with real problems.

Comment: @Pinky - You will get less down votes, and better responses, if you try something yourself first. Then post here if you run into errors or unexpected results. Otherwise, it may sound like you are asking others to write sql for you - and S.O. is not that kind of site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete from emplyoee where empid in(
select e.empid from emplyoee  e 
left outer join emplyoee   e1 on e.empid=e1.empid
left outer join department d on d.managerid=e1.empid
where e1.location='usa'
)
```

Comment: (1) why OUTER join? (a) the first becomes INNER due to the WHERE clause (b) the second makes the link unimportant and discardable (2) When will `e.empid=e1.empid` never match (a) never. it's an identity equivalence (same table, same column). (3) which means that `e1.location='usa'` is the same as `e.location='usa'`, for which `e.empid` from the subquery gets returned. (4) **In summary, you're deleting all employees whose location is in 'usa'** (a) nothing about managers (b) using a screwed up query

Answer (score 5):

This will work on some RDBMS, but not all, if you can tell us which you are using we can provide a more complete solution

```
DELETE FROM employee 
 WHERE emp_id IN (SELECT emp_id FROM department 
                    WHERE manager_id IN 
                         (SELECT emp_id FROM employees WHERE location = "newyork"));
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server solution

```
delete E
  from Employee M
  join department D on D.managerid = M.empid
  join Employee E on E.empid = D.empid
 where M.location = 'usa';
```

Comment: How does it ensures that only those are deleted where the manager's location is **in NewYork**? _"How to delete the emp whose manager is in New York?

"_

Comment: The question is the title or text? hmm.. tough one. Surely you assume OP can change 'usa' to 'newyork'?!